# Cloudflare SSL protocol error

Tags: apache, nginx, cloudflare

An issue I have been experiencing is that once every ~50 pages I load in Google chrome on my website is that chrome gives me an error page saying `SSL Protocol Error`. I am using Flexible SSL and various webapps, like webmin, vestacp, boxbilling and a few mostly static websites. All of these are hosted by nginx, reverse proxying directly to webmin and vestacp. As for the other webapps, the static files are hosted by nginx, reverse proxying to apache2 for php.

I am not entirely sure it is a cloudflare issue yet, but it does (seem to) work normal making plain http requests directly to my server. Of course I'd be surprised if I got any SSL error when using http.

Comment: I would recommend opening a ticket with CloudFlare support.

Comment: All of the other sites I visited that have the same SSL cert are working though. And other websites that are on cloudflare but not on the same cert as my domain are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server request is being proxied through CloudFlare, as long as it is proxied through CloudFlare this issue lies with CloudFlare and there is little you can do to fix it yourself.

I would raise a support request with them and explain the issue, they give preference to clients who pay the most first, therefore you might have to wait to get a response.